# Solving Exam Paper in Free lancing

Tags: halal-haram

Asalam.o.Alaikum

Is it allowed to solve exam question papers of students in freelancing?

For e.g iam a student and iam giving my final exam on basis degree will be given to me. I am unable to pass on my own , therefore i hired a freelancer to solve my exam paper. He solved all questions correctly and i got a "A" Grade though i was not competent for that myself so it it halal or haram?

Please Explain

JAzak Allah
Asim
Pakistan

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rephrase your question to "is it halal to cheat". No, it is not permissible.

> A’ishah (may Allah be pleased with her) said: The Messenger of Allah
> (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Whoever seeks to
> please people by displeasing Allah, Allah will be displeased with him
> and cause people to be displeased with him.”
>
> [Sahih Ibn Hibban 276](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175744/it-is-not-permissible-to-cheat-in-exams-no-matter-what-the-motives)

Shaykh Ibn Baaz (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> Cheating is haraam in exams just as it is haraam in transactions. No
> one has the right to cheat in tests in any subject, and if the teacher
> approves of that then he is a partner in the sin and betrayal.
>
> [Majmoo‘ Fataawa Ibn Baaz, 6/397](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175744/it-is-not-permissible-to-cheat-in-exams-no-matter-what-the-motives)